# CSS full page animation stutter/jank

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm working on a single-page app (SPA) where the user navigates from one (virtual) page to another. I wanted to add a smooth transition where the current page slides off to the left and fades out, while the next page slides onto the screen and fades in.

The following snippet is a sample of this. In Chrome 58 on a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016), the performance tab seems to show wildly variable results. Sometimes the FPS is 60, sometimes 30, sometimes 10, as the ms per frame reaches over 100(?!). During these long frames, I don't see any activity in my own code.

What's wrong here? Why aren't these animations silky smooth?

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (window.animating) return;
  window.animating = true;
  var animator = document.getElementById('animator');
  var content1 = document.querySelector('.content');
  var content2 = document.createElement('div');
  content2.classList.add('content');
  content2.innerHTML = content1.innerHTML;
  content2.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
  content2.style.opacity = 0;
  animator.insertBefore(content2, content1);

  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      var onAnimationEnd = function() {
        if (content1.parentNode) content1.parentNode.removeChild(content1);
        content2.style.transform = '';
        animator.style.animationName = "";
        animator.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd)
        window.animating = false;
      }
      animator.style.animationName = 'slide';
      animator.addEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd);
      content1.style.opacity = 0;
      content2.style.opacity = 1;
    })
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 680px;
}

#animator {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  /* so containers can overlap */
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id=animator>
  <div class=content>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin in semper felis, sit amet bibendum turpis. In enim urna, euismod eget malesuada vel, tristique at ligula. Quisque faucibus vulputate ex in egestas. Vestibulum gravida varius ullamcorper.
      Sed scelerisque nisl dolor, at feugiat tellus porta a. Duis maximus lorem a laoreet pulvinar. Donec felis augue, dapibus ut molestie id, vehicula et tortor. Curabitur vitae tempor massa, eu dapibus magna. Donec facilisis sed purus eget aliquam.
      Curabitur at velit erat. Proin vitae nisl eu odio facilisis pretium in sit amet urna. Aenean imperdiet metus in bibendum fermentum. Nullam eu sollicitudin neque, sit amet aliquam dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
      ac imperdiet nunc, nec convallis elit. In efficitur neque non ullamcorper rhoncus.</p>

    <p>Mauris dictum enim eu consectetur interdum. Integer a sem ac eros tincidunt ultrices. Proin eget vehicula leo. Praesent condimentum tincidunt sollicitudin. Etiam congue, est ut tempor luctus, arcu justo eleifend neque, sed aliquet lacus est eget sapien.
      Maecenas at felis ut nisl tempor placerat. Sed sed tortor ligula. Duis nec tempor nibh, ac tincidunt eros. Quisque enim lacus, elementum vitae lorem sed, efficitur scelerisque magna. Vestibulum quis tellus sit amet neque facilisis tempus. Sed eu
      vulputate felis, quis fringilla neque. Ut interdum congue velit ut cursus.</p>

    <p>Cras volutpat erat magna, vitae molestie urna eleifend non. Ut volutpat nulla id ornare dictum. Sed quis eleifend dui. Fusce sed purus nulla. Curabitur varius eros quis nibh consequat feugiat. Nulla nec metus sapien. Praesent laoreet tempor dui. Maecenas
      eleifend in mauris vitae convallis. Nam lobortis sagittis augue, non porttitor ipsum tempus et. Curabitur eleifend leo non tellus posuere aliquam a eu tellus. Donec augue nisi, aliquet ut egestas quis, interdum in turpis. Mauris efficitur enim ut
      cursus tincidunt. Suspendisse ac lobortis est. Phasellus eget congue dui.</p>

    <p>Etiam a ullamcorper enim. Aenean facilisis nec lectus ac auctor. Mauris id purus porta, elementum arcu et, fringilla ante. Sed a imperdiet tortor. In eu mauris sagittis, porta felis ac, scelerisque orci. Suspendisse vel iaculis tortor. Nulla ut metus
      odio.</p>

    <p>Fusce blandit aliquet purus quis tristique. Suspendisse ac egestas velit. Phasellus eget aliquet dolor. Suspendisse sodales eget nibh quis sagittis. Suspendisse id eros ut neque luctus vehicula quis non arcu. Vivamus vel porta enim, auctor accumsan
      ligula. Praesent varius quis sapien at euismod. In bibendum sem nec viverra molestie. Suspendisse accumsan ornare nulla venenatis imperdiet. Curabitur in justo nec arcu sagittis ultrices eget eget mi. Donec dapibus mauris in orci facilisis pellentesque
      porta ac ipsum. Nulla ornare, augue eget congue scelerisque, ante dui venenatis est, ac pellentesque lacus dui quis augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque ac semper urna. Donec consequat ultrices quam non
      pellentesque. Integer tellus nibh, varius eget sollicitudin nec, accumsan id massa.</p>

    <p>Ut at condimentum nulla. Praesent consectetur semper eros eget pretium. In sapien diam, feugiat quis est a, consequat blandit sem. Fusce augue mi, maximus id ipsum vitae, tempor gravida mauris. Nunc eget velit quam. Sed eget lectus vitae felis porttitor
      sagittis. Sed faucibus, diam euismod congue condimentum, turpis tellus viverra nunc, quis cursus justo felis et magna. Etiam aliquet arcu quam, eget vehicula turpis suscipit nec. Nullam fermentum fringilla risus a scelerisque.</p>

    <p>Phasellus non tortor ut velit commodo accumsan in eget ipsum. Ut sit amet volutpat massa. Mauris viverra sit amet ex vel pulvinar. Nullam tortor nulla, dictum a aliquet sed, tincidunt id enim. Curabitur hendrerit egestas quam, sed mattis purus. In
      varius nec massa nec finibus. Suspendisse magna turpis, fringilla nec justo ut, fermentum feugiat felis. Nulla diam dolor, ultricies in neque et, faucibus suscipit metus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ultrices nisi ac dui porttitor vulputate.</p>

    <p>Vivamus lobortis, turpis sit amet efficitur semper, sapien sapien hendrerit quam, a cursus tellus lectus quis nisl. Curabitur vel massa vitae lectus vulputate tristique sed vitae odio. Nulla ut dapibus enim, ac pulvinar nunc. Sed consequat sed sem
      a sagittis. Curabitur felis orci, semper eu auctor sit amet, gravida vel sem. Praesent pharetra orci ut imperdiet pretium. Ut non est sit amet nunc egestas gravida ut nec velit. Donec lorem leo, maximus ut tortor ac, molestie feugiat neque. Duis
      imperdiet est eleifend lacus pretium, quis eleifend magna malesuada.</p>

    <p>Integer pulvinar ante at lobortis scelerisque. Phasellus vel dapibus ex. Aenean id leo nec mi tincidunt dignissim. Morbi porttitor quis mauris eu ultrices. Vestibulum in nisl ac mauris dignissim tincidunt quis vel leo. Pellentesque laoreet sit amet
      nibh ac porttitor. Maecenas mattis felis ac blandit aliquet. Donec ac commodo felis, eget ultricies turpis. Ut efficitur erat dolor, ut pulvinar leo sagittis eget. Donec eu sem eros. Nullam molestie dapibus velit vel sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum
      primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed tempor nec orci at tempor. Maecenas efficitur sagittis justo, ac placerat nulla iaculis ac. Sed convallis ac neque id fermentum. Curabitur euismod turpis vitae tristique faucibus.</p>

    <p>Vestibulum leo arcu, tincidunt sit amet vulputate nec, rutrum eget nulla. Sed sapien nisl, sagittis sit amet fermentum eget, volutpat tincidunt risus. Fusce ac luctus diam. Vestibulum at est egestas, fermentum erat ac, sodales enim. Nam eu facilisis
      dui. Fusce quis ligula quis mi efficitur tristique rutrum a ante. Maecenas id congue sapien, in vulputate mi. Nam imperdiet venenatis leo. Proin pharetra vehicula est quis rutrum. Donec est eros, dapibus quis vulputate id, maximus et justo. Ut nec
      mi elementum, aliquet dui ac, tempor ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When dealing with animations it's sometimes best to leave the animating to the css and toggle css-classes (to trigger the animations) with js. js animation can get pretty janky (and frustrating to debug), css tends to be smoother.

Comment: Also, changing the content (innerHTML) at runtime is a likely culprit for the glitchy renders.

Comment: translateX is a very expensive animation as it triggers reflow.  The only low cost CSS animations are those that do not trigger reflow - i.e. color, opacity, etc. So long as you are using an animation that triggers reflow, it will never be silky smooth unfortunately as every element on the page must be re-evaluated and redrawn every frame.

Comment: @admcfajn, [**CSS vs. JS Animation**](https://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation)

Comment: Also,  [**CSS animations performance: the untold story**](https://greensock.com/css-performance)

Comment: Thanks @Mi-Creativity I'll give those a read. I've just found that switching to css animations can reduce jank a great deal when jQuery starts getting frustrating. I'd be interested to learn if/how z-indexing could be used to isolate animated elements from the static ones.

Comment: More to the point, the `@keyfrmes slide` seems minsplaced... What about using js/jq `.offset` ?

Comment: After watching the "untold story" video recommended by @Mi-Creativity I tried recreating the animation using JS and requestAnimationFrame. It seems to be approximately the same level of jank IMO. https://jsfiddle.net/dfabulich/byoqdus8/

Comment: @Korgrue [Animating transform doesn't trigger reflow](https://csstriggers.com/transform). Google recommends animating [transform and opacity](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) only.